# Threejs orbitalcontrols set target breaking camera rotation using mouse/touch

Tags: three.js

I am developing a standard panorama viewer, where a 360 picture is placed inside of a sphere and the user can look around using mouse and touch. I am using OrbtialControls for this and it is working fine.
The user can also load a new 360 picture, after loading the picture, I am trying to set the camera direction so that the user is looking in a certain direction. As I am using orbitalControls, I am using control.target.set(x,y,z) to do so. However that causes the camera to lock at that point and if I use the mouse or touch to look around, the camera position changes and it revolves around that point, rather than looking around inside the sphere.
Has anyone else seen this kind of behavior? Do I need to do something

The code is pretty simple.

```js
 controls.reset();
controls.target.set(window.newLookAt.x,window.newLookAt.y,window.newLookAt.z);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving this myself. The issue was that my understanding of  orbitControls was slightly off. All I needed to do was to set the target point in the same direction but way closer to the camera and presto, issue solved and things are working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `controls.target.set(x,y,z)` is to set the pivot point, so what you are facing is the expected behavior

Instead of setting the target *(that has to be (0, 0, 0) in your case)*, why not putting the camera inside a `THREE.Object3D` and rotate this object

```js
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera()
var container = new THREE.Object3D()
container.add( camera )
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 0.1 )

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer )
controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 ) // Optional

container.rotate.y = Math.PI / 2 // Or whatever you want
```